# Does Hyperforce support the Lightning Viz Component for embedding Tableaus in Salesforce pages?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, tableau-crm, hyperforce

We are planning on using the [Lightning Viz Component](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000GF1cSUAT) to embed Tableaus into our Salesforce pages.

I've [read](https://sptechusa.com/blog/what-is-salesforce-hyperforce/) that "every Salesforce app, customization and integrations" will be backward compatible with Hyperforce. But I don't know if that extends to the Viz Component for embedding Tableaus.

After we migrate to Hyperforce, will we still be able to embed Tableaus in our Salesforce pages?